# Fan-out computation in WebApi using async / await

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have say an interface called:

```
interface IExecutor {
   String Name { get; }
   Task<int> Execute();
}
```

And two implementations of it (details are irrelevant and you can assume methods are marked with async and work as expected). Each implementation takes between 2-3 seconds to run and there will ever be between 2 and 5 implementations of IExecutor

I have a controller that needs to run all executors and return the results in as ExecutorResult objects. Where ExecutorResult is:

```
class ExecutorResult {
    int Result; // assume usual get n set
    String ExecutorName;
}
```

Ideally this should happen in a Fan-Out approach.

I have thought of the following approaches:

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
foreach(var executor in executors) {
    tasks.Add(executor.Execute());
}

var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The problem I have with this approach is that I m not sure if this is best practice in an ASP WebAPI application. Also - given I would like to return Result objects - where Result needs an the name of the executor and the int result from Execute the above solution doesn't work as outside of the for loop I no longer have access to the Name property of each executor.

So what is the best practice for this approach (again - given a Web Api application and not a Console app)

Comment: As a best practice you should name the Execute() method ExecuteAsync()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have already is a best practice. What you're doing is *asynchronous concurrency*, which is best done with `Task.WhenAll`.

Note that the code:

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
foreach(var executor in executors) {
  tasks.Add(executor.Execute());
}
var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

can be simplified to:

```
var results = Task.WhenAll(executors.Select(e => e.Execute()));
```

In spite of the countless examples using `List<Task>`, you don't actually have to build one up explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you're looking for somethng like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<ExecutorResult>>();
foreach (var executor in executors)
{
    tasks.Add(((Func<IExecutor, Task<ExecutorResult>>)(
        async (e) => new ExecutorResult
        {
            ExecutorName = e.Name,
            Result = await e.Execute()
        }))(executor));
}

var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

OR, following Stephen Clearly suggestion:

```
var results = Task.WhenAll(
    from executor in executors
    select ((Func<IExecutor, Task<ExecutorResult>>)(
        async (e) => new ExecutorResult
        {
            ExecutorName = e.Name,
            Result = await e.Execute()
        }))(executor))
    );
```

Comment: There is a compile error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
public class Executor : IExecutor
{
   public String Name { get; set;}

   public async Task<int> Execute()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Executing " + Name);
      await Task.Delay(3000);
      Console.WriteLine("Finished Executing " + Name);
      return 0;
   }
}
public async Task<ExecutorResult> Execute(IExecutor executor)
{
    return new ExecutorResult { ExecutorName = executor.Name,
                                Result = await executor.Execute() };
}

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    var executors = new List<IExecutor>
    {
        new Executor { Name = "Executor1" },
        new Executor { Name = "Executor2" },
        new Executor { Name = "Executor3" }
    };

    List<Task<ExecutorResult>> tasks = new List<Task<ExecutorResult>>();

    foreach(var executor in executors)
    {
        tasks.Add(Execute(executor));
    }

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
```